# Why do my textures look dull in the render compared to texture mode?

Tags: rendering

I was recently rendering something to make for GFX (yes it is a Roblox character) and when I finished doing the lighting, positioning the camera, and all that stuff, when I rendered it it turns out like this:

[image: Render]

I have used Blender before, but I haven't in a few months, but it never turned out like this. The colors when I first rendered it when I got the program back then were more vivid. But I'm not even sure if I can fix that. I tried everything, and I cant seem to get rid of this tint, but when I am not rendering the textures and everything come out perfectly fine. If someone can help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like too much glossy or specular refelctions are washing out your colors.

Comment: How could I fix that?